# Android jni read the same path , but not the same

Tags: android, java-native-interface

```java
static void setIntField(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, const char* path,
                        jfieldID fieldID) {
    const int SIZE = 128;
    char buf[SIZE] = "\0";
    jint value = 0;
    if (readFromFile(path, buf, SIZE) > 0) {
        value = atoi(buf);
    }
    env->SetIntField(obj, fieldID, value);
}

static int readFromFile(const char* path, char* buf, size_t size) {
    if (!path)
        return -1;
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        LOGE("Could not open '%s'", path);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t count = read(fd, buf, size);
    if (count > 0) {
        count = (count < size) ? count : size - 1;
        while (count > 0 && buf[count - 1] == '\n')
            count--;
        buf[count] = '\0';
    } else {
        buf[0] = '\0';
    }

    close(fd);
    return count;
}
```

This is my Android JNI code. Why do I read the same path, but the value is not the same twice. I am reading this path `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`.

How to fix it?

`scaling_min_freq` value is 51000. The first time I get 51000. The second time I get 150000.

Comment: Maybe it changes? You're also assuming you read the entire file with a single read. You can't assume that. Read in a loop until EOF.

Comment: I know the reason, it is always changing.